# How to do simple calculation in latex tables

Tags: tables, calculations

Here I wish to do three things:

1) I want my table to be like this one below

[image]

whereas mine is

[image]

2) I want numbers to appear in the same format as their heading p (in bold)

3) I want latex to do some calculation. p in my table represents the proportion of females (females/(males + females)). I am wondering whether latex can do that for me because I have 16 groups and don't wan to calculate each?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|r} 

Group No & Females  & Males & \textbf{p} \\ \hline
1 & 18 & 11 &  \\
2 & 31 & 22 &  \\
3 & 34 & 27 &  \\
4 & 33 & 29 &  \\
5 & 27 & 24 &  \\
6 & 33 & 29 &  \\
7 & 28 & 25 &  \\
8 & 23 & 26 &  \\
9 & 33 & 38 &  \\
10 & 12 & 14 &  \\
11 & 19 & 23 &  \\
12 & 25 & 31 &  \\
13 & 14 & 20 &  \\
14 & 2 & 20 &  \\
15 & 22 & 6 &  \\
16 & 7 & 34 &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See package [spreadtab](http://texdoc.net/pkg/spreadtab).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution with `collcell` and `xparse` (for `\fp_eval:n`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\collectcell\rememberF}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\rememberM}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\computeP}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand{\rememberF}[1]{%
  \gdef\FEMALE{#1}#1%
}
\newcommand{\rememberM}[1]{%
  \gdef\MALE{#1}#1%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\computeP}{}
 {
  \bfseries\fp_eval:n { round ( \FEMALE/(\FEMALE+\MALE) , 2 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c F M P}
\toprule
Group No &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Females} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Males} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{p}} \\
\midrule
1 & 18 & 11 &  \\
2 & 31 & 22 &  \\
3 & 34 & 27 &  \\
4 & 33 & 29 &  \\
5 & 27 & 24 &  \\
6 & 33 & 29 &  \\
7 & 28 & 25 &  \\
8 & 23 & 26 &  \\
9 & 33 & 38 &  \\
10 & 12 & 14 &  \\
11 & 19 & 23 &  \\
12 & 25 & 31 &  \\
13 & 14 & 20 &  \\
14 & 2 & 20 &  \\
15 & 22 & 6 &  \\
16 & 7 & 34 &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Usage of `booktabs` features is not mandatory, but the table layout is better without vertical rules.

[image]

The `F` and `M` column types remember the entry in `\FEMALE` and `\MALE` respectively and print them, the `P` column type computes the ratio and prints it. In the first row it's necessary to use `\multicolumn` so as to avoid these macros to kick in.

The number of decimal digits can be changed in the `\computeP` macro, the value I used is `2`.

Comment: A quick check might be necessary to make sure that `\FEMALE+\MALE` is not zero. But that would be an added bonus.

Comment: @Werner Well, I guess it wouldn't be a meaningful statistics if both groups have zero members.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, using the `spreadtab` package, and also `siunitx`, `booktabs` and `makecell`, to improve the look of the table. The spreadtab package allows to define computing formulae, among which I use `\STcopy{v}{formula}`, where the `v` argument makes the formula be translated for all cells of the same column.

Another feature is I defined a `rowno` counter, so the row numbers in the first column be automatically displayed without having to type them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array, spreadtab, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format = 2.0, table-number-alignment=center}
\newcounter{rowno}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\STautoround{2}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ @{}>{\stepcounter{rowno} \therowno}c SS>{\bfseries}c}}
\toprule
@ \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Group\\ No}} & @ \multicolumn{1}{c}{Females} & @ \multicolumn{1}{c}{Males} & @p\\
\midrule
& 18 & 11 & \STcopy{v}{b2 /(b2+ c2)}\\
 & 31 & 22 & \\
 & 34 & 27 & \\
 & 33 & 29 & \\
 & 27 & 24 & \\
 & 33 & 29 & \\
 & 28 & 25 & \\
 & 23 & 26 & \\
 & 33 & 38 & \\
 & 12 & 14 & \\
 & 19 & 23 & \\
 & 25 & 31 & \\
 & 14 & 20 & \\
 & 2 & 20 & \\
 & 22 & 6 & \\
 & 7 & 34 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]