# is there a way to autofill tables in latex like in excel with equations

Tags: tables, automation, excel

i would like to be able to auto calculate simple values based on other values already present in the tabular environment or a similar environment
i have tried looking on google but couldn't find anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can define table-cell content as variables and do arithmetic operations on them. For numbers, there are the mulitply by, divide by and advance by functions.

Comment: You can look at the [`spreadtab`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab?lang=en) package (is this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209944/how-to-do-simple-calculation-in-latex-tables)?

Comment: BTW, the links in my comment above were from googling "latex tabular calculating spreadsheet" and they were among the fist ten hits... what did you search?